# Необходимо отслеживать, появился ли игрок в зоне видимости бота

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я пишу игру на юнити. Мне необходимо реализовать зону, зайдя в которую, игрок бы провоцировал на себя врагов.
Зона естественно привязана непосредственно к врагу. При обнаружении вошедшего враг разворачивается к нему и направляется, чтоб атаковать.
Я пытался это реализовать через коллайдеры, но в таком случае игрок может атаковать врага ударяя по коллайдеру. Пытался так же реализовать через Physics.CheckSphere(), но в таком случае не получается проверить, кто вошел в зону видимости. А мне желательно, чтоб когда игрок выходит из зоны видимости - враги переставали бы его преследовать. Можно конечно реализовать это через проверку, находится ли он в зоне видимости через тот же Physics.CheckSphere(), а потом в зависимости от этого атаковать найденного еще при старте игрока, но хотелось бы без таких сложностей.

```
    private void Attack()
    {
        if (Physics.Raycast(_head.transform.position, _head.transform.forward, out RaycastHit hitInfo, _attackDistance))
        {
            if (hitInfo.transform.TryGetComponent(out IAttacktableObject attacktableObject))
            {
                attacktableObject.Damaged(_damage);
            }
        }
    }
```

Метод, что производит атаку

Comment: `пытался это реализовать через коллайдеры` Так делай через триггеры

Comment: Bruh, тригерры те же коллайдеры

Comment: Как у тебя игрок врага атакует? При столкновении с коллайдером врага наносится урон?

Comment: Игрок стреляет рейкастом из центра экрана в сторону врага, и если тот на достаточном расстоянии - ему наносится урон

Comment: `QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore` указывай  при рейкасте, тогда он триггеры будет игнорить и взаимодействовать только с коллайдерами.

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь, сори, что слегка спылил изначально. Всю ночь с этим маялся. Не ответишь на этот вопрос открыто, чтоб я мог его пометить, как решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При рейкасте указывай `QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore`, чтобы рейкаст игнорировал триггеры и взаимодействовал только с коллайдерами.

```
if (Physics.RaycastNonAlloc(ray, hits, maxDistance, layerMask, QueryTriggerInteraction.Ignore) > 0)
{
    ///Do stuff
}
```